# Date Comparison of SQL and Java

Tags: java, sql

I want to compare two dates.First date is getting retrieved from system date and other one I'm getting through one query. But here problem is both dates are same as I can see but in If else function I'm getting different result. Below is my code and in output section I have given which output is gonna come with respective function?

```
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
Date currdate = new Date();
System.out.println("****"+dateFormat.format(currdate));
```

Output is : -   2014-01-21

```
stat = con.prepareStatement("select date from finaltbale where tl_id='"+tempmaxid+"'");
rs = stat.executeQuery();
rs.next();
Date tempdate = rs.getDate(1);
```

Output is :-   2014-01-21

```
if(tempdate.equals(currdate)){

        System.out.println("Dates are same");

        }

        else{

        System.out.println("Dates are different");

        }
```

Output is : - Dates are different

Comment: the problem is that `new Date()` also has a time component, whereas the you get from you sql statement probably has a different one

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Oracle? Postgres? What datatype is the `date` column in the table? (btw: `date` is a horrible name for a column)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The system date that you get will also include hours, minutes, seconds and milliseconds. You are only printing out the year, month and day. So they will look the same when you print these but when you compare them with `.equals` it will return false due to the time portion of the dates being different.

You could format the dates and compare the strings from the format to see if they are the same

```
if(dateFormat.format(tempdate).equals(dateFormat.format(currdate))){...}
```

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't recomend comparing strings, but in this case you may want to change the [equals](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29) in your if to [matches](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#matches%28java.lang.String%29), since equals compares to another object so both dates may have the same value but they are completely different, on the other hand, matches compares to a regular expression.

Another way to do that is through the [Calendar](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#method_summary) methods [after](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#after%28java.lang.Object%29), [before](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#before%28java.lang.Object%29) or [compareTo](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#compareTo%28java.util.Calendar%29) witch is the best way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

The [answer by Java Devil](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21243392/642706) is correct.

To elaborate…

"Date" is a tricky word in the worlds of Java, JDBC, and SQL.

You are calling [`getDate`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#getDate(int)) on a ResultSet. That renders a [java.sql.Date](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Date.html) – note the `sql` in the middle there! A java.sql.Date is a java.util.Date adjusted to have a zero time (00:00:00.000) in UTC/GMT (no time zone offset). That adjustment means the internal number of milliseconds since epoch changes.

I'm assuming your line `Date currdate = new Date();` is using java.util.Date. When mixing this kind of SQL and non-SQL code, you should explicitly specify the package on those classes.

So, you are comparing a pair objects which contain a **different number of milliseconds**.

Call the `getTime()` method on both your java.util.Date and your java.sql.Date objects to see their number of milliseconds since [epoch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epoch_%28reference_date%29).

By the way, this is complicated by the fact that the `toString` methods on both java.util.Date and java.sql.Date apply your JVM's default time zone when rendering a string. But neither object actually contains a time zone, just the number of milliseconds since 1970 began in UTC/GMT (no time zone offset).

In SQL, to capture both date and time use the [standard TIMESTAMP type](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL#Date_and_time) or a proprietary type provided by your particular database.

## Joda-Time

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) 2.3 library can be helpful here. Pass either the java.sql.Date or java.util.Date object to a DateTime constructor along with the UTC time zone object to get a clear picture of the value with which you are struggling.

```
java.util.Date date = new java.util.Date( 1390276603054L );
DateTime dateTimeUtc = new DateTime( date, DateTimeZone.UTC );
System.out.println( "dateTimeUtc: " + dateTimeUtc );
```

When run…

```
2014-01-21T03:56:43.054Z
```

## Tip

On a side note…

The comment on the question by a_horse_with_no_name is correct: 'date' is a *terrible* name for a column in your database. Here's the most valuable tip I've learned about SQL…

> The SQL standard promises that a trailing underscore will never be used in any identifier

So if you name every column with a trailing underscore, you never have to worry about conflicts with the many many keywords and other identifiers defined by both the standard and by many proprietary extensions in various databases.

So use `date_`.